# jPlayer jPlayerAndroidFix not working?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, jplayer

I'm working on a website using jPlayer. The problem appeared when I tried to use it with my android phone, so I started recoding it. Now I'm trying to use the jPlayerAndroidFix class. I'm doing it just like in the example given in the source code in the tutorial, and still it's not working. 
Here's the code:

```
function playSound(sound) {
    if (playToggle) {
        return;
    }

    var id = "#jplayer-play";
    var media = {
        mp3: sound
    }; 
    var options = {
        swfPath: $('body').data('jplayer-swf'),
        solution: 'flash,html',
        wmode:"window",
        supplied: 'mp3',
        preload: 'metadata',
        volume: 0.8,
        muted: false,
        errorAlerts: false,
        warningAlerts: false,
        customCssIds: true
    };
    var myAndroidFix = new jPlayerAndroidFix(id, media, options);
    myAndroidFix.setMedia(media);
    myAndroidFix.play();
}
```

Important thing to add - the audio is received dynamically, for example from a link:
http://granie.t-mobile.pl/sets/play/69986

and that's the "sound" variable.

What may cause the problem? What am I doing wrong?
The jPlayerAndroidFix class can be found in the source code of 
http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-01-android/?theme=0

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ? not working is not a specific issue.